# Pentax 67 on a Berlebach tripod Model 8043?

Tags: tripod, pentax

I think about buying a tripod for my Pentax 67. My longest lens is 165 mm.  I am considering the [Berlebach Model 8043](https://www.optics-pro.com/made-of-wood/berlebach-wooden-tripod-model-8043/p,8107#tab_bar_1_select) as it is within my budget. (*My budget is limited*).

I have read good feedback about Berlebach's tripods - great vibration damping.

**Question:** Will a Pentax 67 with a 167mm lens be stable on the Berlebach Model 8043 tripod?

Comment: If you could provide a link it would help people answer your question.

Comment: Thank You, Eric

Comment: Casting my mind back to an article I read ~20 years ago, it said that wooden tripods are much better at absorbing vibration than metal tripods, just they are big and heavy and cumbersome, making them an unpopular/impractical choice. But if you want vibration damping, then I think a Berlebach is a good way to go.

Answer (score 2):

From the Tripod link:

> Load capacity (kg)    8

From this [random link](http://web.mit.edu/dennis/www/pentax67/lens-info.html) about Pentax 67 lenses, the heaviest 165mm lens is:

> SMC Pentax 67 165mm f/2.8  .. 0.835 kg

From [Pentax 6x7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentax_6%C3%977) wiki, the camera:

> weighing 2.3 kilograms (5.1 lb) with the plain prism and standard (105
> mm f/2.4) lens

From the same lens link, the 105 f/2.4 lens weighs 0.59 kg, so your maximum camera + lens weight is: 2.3 - 0.59 + 0.835 = 2.545 kg.  This is well within the load capacity of your tripod.

However the stability of the camera is also going to depend on the tripod head that you use. You will need to select a head with a suitable load capacity (and the weight of the head itself needs to be included in the total tripod load).  While not absolutely necessary, a tripod head will allow you to easily aim the camera at your subject.

Finally I note that on that tripod link it says:

> This product is no longer stocked and therefore cannot be purchased
> until further notice.

So maybe you need another tripod selection????

Comment: I am sorry that I did not ask my question precisely. Of course, your calculation is alright. However, one can read on the internet that in the case of Pentax 67, the problem is not so simple, because of high vibration coming from shutter release/mirror. Or in general, P67 is a massive camera.  Anyway, thank you for your contribution! Also, the tripod is still available in my country (only one piece left, haha)

Comment: @nabzdyczony Yeah, I think I have read discussions about large amounts mirror slap on things like this camera.  I have no practical experience with one, so my only advice would be "mirror lock up".  I have used Mamiya RB/RZ 67 and for what little I have done I haven't seen any problems.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the best tripod is the one you have with you.

And so it’s more a matter of how the photographer works than anything else. A good choice for the studio might not be good for a photo walk. Long exposures by the sea have different considerations than sunlit portraits in a city park.

For me, legs tend to matter less than heads. Mostly legs are either good enough or not while heads get incrementally better and the head is where small improvements make better work flow. The head is where I touch the tripod to adjust the camera.

Even a robust set of legs may suffer in gale winds and just about all legs will work in calm air.  If the cumbersomeness of heavy legs makes it more difficult to make pictures then lighter legs might be a better choice if they get used more readily.